# I am trying to loop through an ArrayList to find the lowest value of a sensor reading

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

My instructions are: Create a sensor object that refers to element zero. Write a for loop that starts at element 1, loops through all the elements of the arraylist and check to see if the value of the sensor reading is smaller than element zero. I am supposed to assume that element zero has the minimum value already. If the value is smaller, set that as the minimum value. Here is the code I have, but it is not finding the minimum value.

```
public int findMinReadingIndex() {
        ArrayList<SensorReading> sensorReadings = new ArrayList<>();
        sensorReadings.get(0);
        int minIndex = 0;
        for(int i=1; i< sensorReadings.size(); i++) {
            if (this.sensorReadings.get(i).getValue() < i)
                minIndex = i;
        }
            return minIndex;
    }
```

Comment: what language is this? java

Comment: When you create a new arraylist, then there are no elements. sensorReadings.get(0) will not return anything as there is nothing in the list

Comment: Yes, it is Java. My apologies.

Comment: I took out the new arraylist, but left sensorReadings.get(0), the program still compiles, but still gives the wrong min value

Comment: please see my answer. made a small change to your code.

Comment: I plugged it in, and I get a compatible types error. Required int, float found.

Comment: which line is error?

Comment: int minReading = sensorReadings.get(0).getValue();

Comment: does this work?

Comment: same error on int reading = this.sensorReadings.get(index).getValue();

Comment: see changed code below. instead of int reading, its now float reading

Comment: `sensorReadings.get(0);` only compiles because it does nothing. You aren't storing the value anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to focus on the problem: you have a list, and you want to find an index with minimum value. So you have to write method that accepts `List<SensorReading>` and retrieves `int` value. Note, that using `get()` is not optimal, especially if you do not know concrete implementation of the `List`. You have to use iterator instead.

```
public int findMinReadingIndex(List<SensorReading> sensorReadings) {
    int minIndex = 0;
    int minValue = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(SensorReading sensorReading : sensorReadings) {     
        if(i == 0 || sensorReading.getValue() < minValue) {
            minValue = sensorReading.getValue();
            minIndex = i;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: @LuCio Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Minor change is below:

```
public int findMinReadingIndex() {
    ArrayList<SensorReading> sensorReadings = new ArrayList<>();
    float minReading = sensorReadings.get(0).getValue();
    int minIndex = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index < sensorReadings.size(); index ++) {
        float reading = this.sensorReadings.get(index).getValue();
        if (reading < minReading)
            minIndex = index;
    }
        return minIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using `Java 8` one liner code use stream with Comparator API.

```
SensorReading minVal = sensorReadingList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(SensorReading::getValue))
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

System.out.println(minVal.getValue());
```

1. First of all calling `stream()` method on the list to get a stream of
   values from the list.
2. After that call to `min()` method on the stream to get the minimum
   value from the list.
3. We are passing a lambda function as a comparator, sort the list and
   deciding the minimum value.
4. After that we call `orElseThrow()` to throw an exception if no value
   is received from `min()`

Comment: Or just `Collections.min(sensorReadingList, Comparator.comparing(SensorReading::getValue)`